# Is it possible to restrict access to Sharepoint online for download and sync but allow printing?

Tags: sharepoint-online, online, printing

My users has unmanaged devices. I want to restrict online access only to Sharepont Online.
So they cannot download documents and upload again, they should view and edit online.
But these users should be able to print on their local printer.
When it is restricted they stil can use printscreen so it is bad for users to restrict printing.
Is it possible to allow printing while it is not allowed to download and to documents locally??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by applying the Azure Information right management (IRM) policy. If in your environment Azure IRM policy is enabled in the Office 365 admin center, you will get the below configuration option in library settings:

- Set additional IRM library settings
- Configure document access rights
- Set group protection and credentials interval

There, you need to configure the **Configure document access rights**.

For details refer to the below article:

[Enable and configure information rights management (IRM) in SharePoint Online](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/enable-and-configure-information-rights-management-irm-in-sharepoint-online/)

And also, if we go to the document link settings, under the Other Settings, the following options will be available.

- Allow Editing
- Set expiration date
- **Block Download**

So, using the link setting also we can control the document downloading.

For details refer to the below article:

[Block Downloading For View-Only Links In SharePoint Online And OneDrive](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-online-onedrive-block-download-for-view-only-links/)

**OR**

You can create a custom access level for the view-only document, like below:

[image: View Only permission]

Source:

[How to Restrict Download & Print Option for SharePoint Online Document library](https://www.cloudfronts.com/restrict-download-and-print-option-for-sharepoint-online-document-library/)